# Velocity, acceleration, derivatives without function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm having trouble with an exercise about position, velocity and acceleration. 
Apologies for the formatting but the prompt has a graph. 
[image: prompt]

So I was able to fill out the table up to a certain point, but I"m having issues understanding how I can find the velocity if I don't have the function. I know that I should use the derivatives, but without having the expression of the function, how can I find it?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: But who writed the values in the "velocity" column ?

Comment: The implicity assumption seems constant speed. This means that in the first part : $6$ meters travelled in $2$ sec = $3 { \text m / \text s}$.

Comment: I did, I tried to guess them based on the relationship of change in position over time. But I'm not sure about what I did and also, how doest that allow me to get to question d? I can't seem to understand if I can find acceleration without the function

Comment: Acceleration is the derivative of velocity (second derivative of position) with respect to time. Constant velocity means zero acceleration.

Comment: Ok, I'm a little bit confused. Because the velocity I found in the column is a constant (no x), but it does change, so does that mean that acceleration will be 0 in every case?

Comment: In all separate cases, acceleration is zero. Acceleration and position have a “quadratic relation” (not even sure if this is the proper term), so you need at least $t^2$ in your $s(t)$ function to have acceleration. (A linear function for position ALWAYS results in zero acceleration.)

Comment: Hmm got it, but is this function linear? The graph is not always straight and change constant isn't it? So basically, the acceleration at t=9 would be 0? Thanks, sorry for all the questions, I'm just super confused

Comment: The lines are most certainly straight. Your $s(t)$ function has to be a parabola at least (second-degree) for there to be acceleration. And yes, the acceleration is $0$ there.

Comment: Right, silly me

Answer (score 2):

If the velocity is constant, which is indicated by the fact that the position-time graph is a straight line, you can just take any two points off the graph and use $v=\frac {\Delta s}{\Delta t}$.  Any two points on the segment will do.  For example, from $t=2$ to $t=6$ it moves from $+6$ to $-10$, so the velocity is $\frac {-10-(+6)}{6-2}=-4$

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But also I have the column about speed. Am I correct to assume that speed if the same as velocity just positive (since velocity is constant anyway?)

Comment: Speed is scalar. The $+$ or $-$ sign in velocity indicates direction, but scalars don’t have direction (vectors do), so you only take the magnitude (positive value).

Comment: Got it. Amazing, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just look at the slope of the graph. An upward slope indicates motion to the right of the origin/starting point, or positive velocity, and vice-versa. As an example, in the interval $0 < t < 2$, the object travels $6$ meters in $2$ seconds, hence a velocity of $3 \frac{m}{s}$. You continue finding the slope of each “section” of the graph. Just remember that velocity depends on whether the slope is upward or downward, while speed is a scalar, not a vector, so it’s always positive.

Finally, acceleration is the derivative of velocity with respect to time. A linear graph for position means constant velocity, hence acceleration is $0$.

For instance:

$$s(t) = nt \implies v(t) = n \implies a(t) = 0$$

Notice how you need one higher power for position (something involving $t^2$) so you get a non-zero acceleration, such as

$$s(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2 \implies v(t) = at \implies a(t) = a$$

for some constant $a$.

Hence, for a **linear** position-time graph, you just find the slope, which becomes the velocity.

Comment: Right, the slope becomes the velocity and is constant, got it. Thanks

Comment: Exactly. When you take the derivative of that constant slope, it becomes $0$. Hence, the acceleration becomes $0$.

Comment: Sorry guys, just a little confused by the end of the problem. I worked through the rest. So the acceleration is 0 at t=9 because of what we said previously. But one question asks for the displacement between 0 and 12. I understand that displacement is the derivative of the velocity function right? So since we have velocity has a constant is it going to be 0 as well here? I'm confused because they are constant on each interval, but are changing on different intervals. I understand they don't have variables though. Thanks

Comment: I’m not sure what work you have to show. You could just look at the first and last points and see how the position changed. The objects displaced $6$ meters rightward. (Zero calculation, just inspection.) If you have to show your work, find the displacement of each “section” individually (be sure to get the signs correctly) and just add them up.

Comment: Oh ok, I was imaging it would be something with derivatives again. But this makes sense. thanks I

Comment: No problem! ${}{}{}$